# Transformation of coordinate systems

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, layers, arcgis-10.5

I have two layers - the first is in 5514 (S-JTSK_Krovak_East_North; sr_0.shp) and the second in 2180 (ETRS_1989_Poland_CS92; pl.shp). I think the coordinate system of both layers is correct. I need to transform the layer coordinate system of the second layer from 2180 to 5514. I tried to do it using Qgis 3.2.3 (save as with new coordinate system 5514), and all possible transformations in Arcgis 10.5 to 5514 and also WGS84. I tried to use also Project tool or my own custom transformation as someone here advised me. However, layers still do not overlap, the shift between them is only about 0.5-2 metres or more, according to the selected transformation. I don't know if I am doing something wrong or where is the problem

Here you can find my layers:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yM5XDZ6ndC9W1_dpS9A39HShwwW-gTzh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please confirm that your layer is first in the correct coordinate system. If it is not, projecting it will be incorrect. Second, check to make sure your second layer is in the correct coordinate system as well.

Comment: Could please share your files or add some screen shots of the layers projection information.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for providing your shapefiles.  I did not get the custom transformation to work either,  However, the project tool recommended this geographic transformation, and they aligned after running it:

[image]

Here is the geoprocessing history:

Project

Parameters

Input Dataset or Feature Class     pl
Output Dataset or Feature Class     C:\Users\{user}\Documents\Temp\pl_project2
Output Coordinate System     PROJCS["S-JTSK_Krovak_East_North",GEOGCS["GCS_S_JTSK",DATUM["D_S_JTSK",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Krovak"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Pseudo_Standard_Parallel_1",78.5],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9999],PARAMETER["Azimuth",30.28813975277778],PARAMETER["Longitude_Of_Center",24.83333333333333],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Center",49.5],PARAMETER["X_Scale",-1.0],PARAMETER["Y_Scale",1.0],PARAMETER["XY_Plane_Rotation",90.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Geographic Transformation     'S_JTSK/05_To_ETRS_1989_1 + S_JTSK_To_S_JTSK/05_1'

Input Coordinate System     PROJCS["ETRS_1989_Poland_CS92",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-5300000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",19.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9993],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
Preserve Shape     NO_PRESERVE_SHAPE
Maximum Offset Deviation
Vertical     NO_VERTICAL

Messages
Start Time: Tuesday, June 28, 2022 9:53:36 AM
Succeeded at Tuesday, June 28, 2022 9:53:39 AM (Elapsed Time: 2.17 seconds)

Below is a comment that was unsuccessful:

I am not sure if the projection is possible, but I created a custom transformation from 2180 to 5514 using ESRI ArcGIS create custom transformation tool (https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/tool-reference/data-management/create-custom-geographic-transformation.htm).  This is the result:

```
GEOGTRAN["To_5514_From_2180",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],GEOGCS["GCS_S_JTSK",DATUM["D_S_JTSK",SPHEROID["Bessel_1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],METHOD["Null"]]
```

This .gtf file was created at C:\Users\usernamefolder\AppData\Roaming\Esri\ArcGISPro\ArcToolbox\CustomTransformations.  After I created the custom transformation on my windows machine.  I added a shapefile to my arcgis pro project with the following projection(2180):

```
PROJCS["ETRS_1989_Poland_CS92",GEOGCS["GCS_ETRS_1989",DATUM["D_ETRS_1989",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",-5300000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",19.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9993],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

I copied the custom .gtf file to the same folder as my shapefile.
Using the project tool in arcgis pro, i projected from 2180 to S-JTSK_Krovak_East_North (5514) without tool error.  ArcGIS pro automatically populated my custom transformation file (To_5514_From_2180.gtf).

[image]

Comment: I tried transformation S_JTSK/05_To_ETRS_1989_1 + S_JTSK_To_S_JTSK/05_1, but it is always the same shift :(

Comment: Output coordinate system: PROJCS['S-JTSK_Krovak_East_North',GEOGCS['GCS_S_JTSK',DATUM['D_S_JTSK',SPHEROID['Bessel_1841',6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Krovak'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',0.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Pseudo_Standard_Parallel_1',78.5],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9999],PARAMETER['Azimuth',30.28813975277778],PARAMETER['Longitude_Of_Center',24.83333333333333],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Center',49.5],PARAMETER['X_Scale',-1.0],PARAMETER['Y_Scale',1.0],PARAMETER['XY_Plane_Rotation',90.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]

Comment: Input coordinate system: PROJCS['ETRS_1989_Poland_CS92',GEOGCS['GCS_ETRS_1989',DATUM['D_ETRS_1989',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',-5300000.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',19.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9993],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]] ,

Comment: Or could you share your transformed layer (pl) please, if it is really aligned to the layer in 5514 (sr)? It would be very helpful for me

Comment: After closer inspection, I see that you are correct.  They are close to being aligned, but they are not exactly aligned.  If I figure anything out, I will post an update